# Disable Dash reveal animation

Tags: unity-dash, 13.04

How can I disable Dash reveal animation. When I try to open Dash it takes up to 2 seconds to open it, that's slow for me. I noticed it uses fade out animation while opening so I think when I disable that animation, reveal time will be much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using compiz-config tool. You can disable most of animations in your Ubuntu using it. But be aware! You might end up with disabled Unity, if you do something wrong!

To install open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then run it from dashboard. You cannot disable all of the animations, but you will notice there are much less of them. I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Run it on the consoler with `ccsm`. It seems like the setting "enable low graphics mode" in the Unity Plugin settings seems to solve a slow unity dash

Answer (score 0):

As has been answered in the thread [How to disable all Unity animations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138622/how-to-disable-all-unity-animations), this animation is hardcoded in the Unity source code. You can only disable it by modifying the source code, or work around it by using the unity- & compiz tools described there.